# How to know when an object is deallocated in Java?

Tags: java, object, lifecycle

I want to know when an object is deallocated in Java?

If there is a something like `deinit` in Swift, I can release some resources at there.
ex)

```
deinit {
     myResource1.dispose()
     myResource2.release()
     someOtherResource.close()
     ....
}
```

Is it a bad practice in Java, so that I have to find another way?

Specifically, I want to know when a row in a list view dies.

Comment: `I want to know when a row in a list view dies.` - Can you post the relevant code in the post? Java automates the reclamation of memory, but not other resources. A `finalize()` method can help ensure that resources are released eventually but *not in a timely fashion*.  You may want to take a look at [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike constructors, there are no destructors or de-init in Java. When the instance is no more reachable (*no more references to the object*), it will automatically Garbage collects by JVM.

You can try implementing [`finalize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) method in your Class.

> Called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object.

Comment: You should not use finalize() for that. You have no guarantee when or if ever this method is called by the GC. At least you can be sure it won't be called before the object's memory gets reclaimed by GC which is typically much after the reference got out of sight. Java just does not have this type of functionality, that's why there are close() methods on everything that has to free resources.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer So we have to write our own method and call the method where ever necessary. Right

Comment: `finalize()` is now deprecated. See documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 1):

Employee class :

```
class Employee {
    public int id;

    public Employee(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.finalize();
        System.out.println(this.id + " Garbage Collected");
    }
}
```

MainClass :

```
public class TestMain  {
public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Employee p = new Employee(111);
    Employee p2 = new Employee(222);
    p = null;
    p2 = null;
    System.gc();
}

}
```

N.B : Though its not sure whether garbage collector will be called or not even if we call gc() method